# How to get data inside model via relation name

Tags: laravel, relationship

How to get data inside model via relation name. but the bad attitude of the side send forward i.e. text
this is a simple example:

```
public function show(Product $product): JsonResponse
{
    $relation = 'brand';
    $products = $product->{$relation}->getFillable();
```

It worked, but it only worked for one element.
How to get into the eloquent geth?
because there are many elements and each element has BelongsTo | HasMany relations

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show(Product $product): JsonResponse{
  $product->load('brand');
  dd($product); //will show all brand relationship function from product model
}
```

Comment: brand will come from the Request params. and in show method my my example is working need in get method on more elements